# Meteor ReactLink integration

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am interested in two way binding.
How can I use Meteor-React with ReactLink ?
I tried this package:
https://github.com/victoransel/meteor-react-linkedstate-mixin

But when I include both the meteor and reactlink mixin, I get an error :
linkState is not a function

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add **React.addons.LinkedStateMixin** to your component mixins:

```
YourComponent = React.createClass({    
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState(){
         return {
             test: ""

         }
    }
});
```

This should allow you to link state like this within your render method:

```
<input type="text" valueLink={this.linkState('test')} />
```